# How to get latitude , longitude from mapKit in iOS?

Tags: ios, frameworks, mapkit

I have integrated to my project the mapkit framework and everything works fine. I just show in a map the users current position like this :

```
mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    MKUserLocation *userLocation = mapView.userLocation;
    //numbers show map zoom. 500,500 = map stretches 500 meters to the North and the South of current location
    MKCoordinateRegion region =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (userLocation.location.coordinate,1000,1000);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

The problem is that i need to store to 2 variables the latitude and longitude of the current position but where are these values stored??

I tried to print the below but it gives me 0.000.

```
NSLog(@"Latitude: %f" , mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"Longitude: %f" , mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

Basically, the MapView will call this location once it has determined the user's location.  If you check **userLocation** on the fly, it's not guaranteed.

You can find the rest of the delegate methods in the **MKMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKMapViewDelegate

Comment: I had this implemented of course so that i can update the user location! But now i tried to put the nslogs inside this function and it works!! but why didnt it work in the viewdidload??

Comment: Once the view loads and you set 'mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;' it has to go out and find the location which can take a minute.  It's an asynchronous task... that's why the data is not available immediately.  How about marking this as the answer since it fixed your issue ;)

Comment: That was very interesting. Thank you for helping me clear this out :)

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"Latitude: %f" , userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude: %f" , userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
}
```

Comment: i just did as stated above :) thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by providing the address as text.

```
geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];    

[geocoder geocodeAddressString:@"1 Infinite Loop" 
  completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
 for (CLPlacemark* aPlacemark in placemarks)
 {
     // Process the placemark.
 }
}];
```

Its explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = locations.lastObject;
    NSLog(@"Latitude: %f" , self.mapview.userLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude: %f" , self.mapview.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);


}
```